# What is next step? I can boot from CD bot not from disk

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I just installed ubuntu-14.04.2 on my HP elitebook 8440p laptop. I set it for dual boot with windows 7. I set up a 100GB partition for Ubuntu. The laptop has 8GB of RAM and intel core i7 processor. I can bring up Ubuntu when I boot from CD. I can still boot Windows 7. When I try booting up Ubuntu from disk I can see the disk light flashing for a while and my screen goes from completely dark to "slightly lit" but I never get to an Ubuntu login screen. What would be the next step to diagnose/fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should start with windows, and after that, install Ubuntu. Ubuntu needs 2 partitions: one EXT4 at least 8 GB, and one swap at least 8 Gb. Hope it will help.

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu without a swap partition, it isn't recommended, but possible.

Comment: Thanks to all. Using "nomodeset" got me up and running. Loading the Nvidia driver via the software update centre got me up and running with good graphics.